# Handle Token Expiration in WSO2

Tags: authentication, wso2, token, wso2-identity-server

We are using wso2 in the backend to generate token and validating each service against the token. We set the default expiration time is 2 Hrs. My Question is-

If the user is continuously using the application without any idle time and in between token get expired, how we can handle it(Maybe we can use refresh token, however- the documentation says we can use a refresh token only once). Is there any way to handle token with idle time? Or do you have a better idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you refresh an access token using the refresh grant type, you get a new refresh token too which you can use for the next time.

For some reason, if you want to keep the same refresh token, you can change the `<RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant>` configuration to `false` in `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` file.

Comment: Do you mean, just we need to change **RenewRefreshTokenForRefreshGrant** as false and each request it'll get me new token?

Comment: no it's the opposite of that. true gives you a new token always which is the default.